# Access to document web parts and widgets in code for a given Kentico TreeNode

Tags: kentico

I asked this question [over on the Kentico devnet](http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/access-in-code-to-details-of-all-web-parts-and-widgets-used-on-specific-document) but haven't had a definitive answer.

I have a particular requirement for a Kentico 8.2 implementation where in code, given a specific `TreeNode`, I'd like to find first all the zones on the template being used then, for each zone, get the details of all web parts **and widgets** used in those zones.

In my case I do not need to worry about template inheritance. None of my pages implement template inheritance.

I found [this post on the old Kentico forums](https://devnet.kentico.com/forums/f54/fp3/t28475/how-do-you-find-all-the-webparts-and-widgets-on) which suggested I might be able to do use `PageInfoProvider` to get a `PageInfo` object for the relevant `TreeNode` then use its `PageTemplateInfo` property to gain access to what I need.

However, I don't see a `PageTemplateInfo` property of `CMS.DocumentEngine.PageInfo`. There is `DesignPageTemplateInfo` and `UsedPageTemplateInfo`. I thought maybe `UsedPageTemplateInfo` would be the one, and it does indeed include the correct zones in its `WebPartZones` collection. But I don't see the web parts (actually, widgets) I'm expecting in the zones' `WebParts` collections.

I guess what I'm asking is, how can I use API to gain access to the content of the `DocumentWebParts` column from `dbo.CMS_Document` as a structured object? I've realised I can get access to the information I need by calling `.GetProperty("DocumentWebParts")` on `TreeNode`, but this is unstructured XML. I presume somewhere in the API I can get this information as a structured object.

Does anyone know how I might access the details I need? Thanks.

P.S. My template uses the ASPX+portal model.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my second answer on the DevNet, you cannot specifically use the `cms_document` table simply because webparts function within templates and not with a specific page.  Widgets on the other hand are specific per page even if the page has the same template as another page.  Take a [look at the example on the DevNet](http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/access-in-code-to-details-of-all-web-parts-and-widgets-used-on-specific-document) I provided, it should get you what you're looking for.